# Django Admin Change View is stuck because of __str__ method of related field

Tags: python, django

I have this model in `accounts.models`:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(BaseModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User, related_name="user_profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # ...

   def __str__(self) --> str:
     return self.user.username
```

And the following in `memberships.models`:

```py
class ExternalServiceProfileMembership(BaseModel):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    expires_at = models.DateTimeField()
    profile = models.ForeignKey(
        "accounts.UserProfile",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="ext_memberships",
    )
    plan = models.ForeignKey("memberships.MembershipPlan", on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    ext_subscription_id = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

When I try to access the admin view of an individual `ExternalServiceProfileMembership` object (for example: http://localhost:8000/admin/memberships/externalserviceprofilemembership/1/change/), the site gets stuck, eventually returning a `503`. So I started out commenting out fields in the `AdminModel`, and once I remove `profile`, the object change view loaded fine.

I brought back `profile` into `AdminModel` but removed `UserProfile`'s `__str__()` method, and it also worked. Which makes me think the whole issue is with this method; but I have no idea why.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This is an N+! problem. You should fetch the objects with: `ExternalServiceProfileMember.objects.select_related('profile', 'profile__user')`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - why is it an `N+!` problem? what does this `+!` mean exactly? Also, I'm talking about an individual object admin view, how should I `select_related` there?

Comment: @zerogedge: sorry, I mean N+1. Because for each `ExternalServiceProfileMember`, you will make two extra queries, so that will eventually go in timeout. See https://scoutapm.com/blog/finding-and-fixing-n-1s-in-django-apps

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - I'm familiar with this problem but I'm not sure this applies here. Each individual `ExternalServiceProfileMembership` currently has one `UserProfile`, which always has only one `User`. Also, I currently only have `ExternalServiceProfileMembership` object in the database. This doesn't seem like a timeout issue to me, and more like some sort of circular reference..?

Comment: exactly, thus if you `str(..)` on the `ExternalServiceProfileMember`, it will fetch the related item (the `Profile`) into memory, and since you also apply `str` on that profile, it will thus make an extra query for the `User`, so *per* `ExternalServiceProfileMember`, you make two extra queries.

Comment: On the change page for `ExternalServiceProfileMembership`, the `profile` dropdown displays the name of every user. This causes one extra query for every user in the dropdown. You could try adding `profile` to [`autocomplete_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields). The other option, which is more complicated, is to create a custom form that uses `select_related` to use an inner join to fetch all of the users.

Comment: @Alasdair - this is the correct analysis of what's happening. Please add as an answer so I can accept. (I've simply made this a `readonly` field because I'm not supposed to edit it anyway). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the change page for `ExternalServiceProfileMembership`, the `profile` dropdown displays the name of every user. This causes one extra query for every user in the dropdown.

The quick fix is to add `'profile'` to [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields), [`autocomplete_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) or [`raw_id_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.raw_id_fields). These three options mean that a single profile is displayed on the change form, so there is only one extra query to fetch the user.

Another approach, which is more complicated, is to create a custom form that overrides the queryset to use `select_related` to fetch all of the users, then use that form in your model admin.